# Need to know how to replace the Flickr gallery with a list of hosted images in this slider gallery

Tags: javascript, css

Sorry if I'm missing anything here. I'd like to use this codepen example as a jumping off point for a range-slider actuated image gallery. Right now it's pulling the images from Flickr but I'd like to use my own hosted images. I know HTML and CSS but not Javascript. If anyone could help me with this or suggest a different approach I'd greatly appreciate it. Here's the link to the Codepen - https://codepen.io/tagger_bomb/pen/yLMvzEo.

**HTML**

```
<section class="timemachine">
<form action="">
  <input type="range" />
</form>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

section {
  text-align: center;
}
figure {
  margin: 0;
}
h2 {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 5em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
/*   bottom: 0; */
/*   right: 40%; */
}

section > figure {
  position: absolute;
  height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  justify-content: center;
}

section > figure > img {
  height: inherit;
}

section > figure {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

input {
  width: 20vw;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>

var images;
function jsonFlickrApi(data) {
  console.log(data);
  images = data.photos.photo.map(function(photo){return photo.url_z});
  image_elements = images.map(function(mg, i) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = mg;
    var numb = document.createElement('h2');
    numb.textContent = i+1;
    var fig = document.createElement('figure');
    fig.appendChild(img);
    fig.appendChild(numb);
    document.querySelector('section').appendChild(fig); 
    return fig;
  });
   var slider = document.querySelector('input');
  slider.min = 0;
  slider.max = slider.value = images.length - 1;
  image_elements[slider.max].style.opacity = 1;
  // slider.step = 0.01;
  slider.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  // console.log(Math.floor(e.target.value));
    image_elements.forEach(function(e){e.style.opacity=0;
                                       // e.style.zIndex=-100;
                                      });
    image_elements[Math.floor(e.target.value)].style.opacity = 1;
    // image_elements[Math.floor(e.target.value)].style.zIndex=100;
   
}); 
}
 
</script>
<script src="https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.people.getPublicPhotos&api_key=603db98e0031fb25a3e3a6fc44502683&user_id=25053835@N03&per_page=50&format=json&extras=description,license,date_upload,date_taken,owner_name,icon_server,original_format,last_update,geo,tags,machine_tags,o_dims,views,media,path_alias,url_sq,url_t,url_s,url_q,url_m,url_n,url_z,url_c,url_l,url_o">


  


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The array `urls` contains the URLs of your hosted images.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

section {
  text-align: center;
}
figure {
  margin: 0;
}
h2 {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 5em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
/*   bottom: 0; */
/*   right: 40%; */
}

section > figure {
  position: absolute;
  height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  justify-content: center;
}

section > figure > img {
  height: inherit;
}

section > figure {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

input {
  width: 20vw;
}
```

```html
<section class="timemachine">
<form action="">
  <input type="range" />
</form>
</section>

<script>
  
  let urls = [
    'https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=1',
    'https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=2',
    'https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=3',
    'https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=4',
  ];
  
  function loadImages() {

    images = urls;
    console.log(urls);
    image_elements = images.map(function(mg, i) {
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = mg;
      var numb = document.createElement('h2');
      numb.textContent = i+1;
      var fig = document.createElement('figure');
      fig.appendChild(img);
      fig.appendChild(numb);
      document.querySelector('section').appendChild(fig); 
      return fig;
    });
     var slider = document.querySelector('input');
    slider.min = 0;
    slider.max = slider.value = images.length - 1;
    image_elements[slider.max].style.opacity = 1;
    // slider.step = 0.01;
    slider.addEventListener('input', function(e) {

      image_elements.forEach(
        function(e){e.style.opacity=0;

                                        });
      image_elements[Math.floor(e.target.value)].style.opacity = 1;


  }); 
}
  
  loadImages();

</script>
```